# Implementation of Incomplete Fermi-Dirac Integral in Mathematica

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I'm working on a special algorithm to implement a more accurate effective mass calculation for hole carriers in silicon in *Mathematica*. This rather involved algorithm uses incomplete Fermi-Dirac Integrals of the form:

$$\mathscr F_j(x,b)=\frac1{\Gamma(j+1)}\int_b^\infty \frac{t^j}{e^{t-x}+1}\mathrm dt$$

```
Fincomplete[j_, x_, b_] :=1/Gamma[j + 1] Integrate[t^j/(E^(t - x) + 1), {t, b, ∞},
                                                   Assumptions -> j > 0]
```

A call to this function with $b=0$ yields the complete Fermi-Dirac integral representation by the nicely implemented `PolyLog` function within *Mathematica*:

```
In[1]:=  Fincomplete[j, x, 0]
Out[1]:= -PolyLog[1 + j, -E^x]
```

However, if one wants to evaluate the incomplete Fermi-Dirac integral, the expression stays unevaluated, indicating that there is no straightforward solution available.

```
In[2]:=  Fincomplete[j,x,b]
Out[2]:= Integrate[t^j/(1 + E^(t - x)), {t, b, ∞}, Assumptions -> j > 0]/Gamma[1 + j]
```

Now, my question(s):

1. Any idea which of the multitude of mathematical functions within *Mathematica* could be leveraged to implement the incomplete Fermi-Dirac integral? Could the [Nielsen generalized polylogarithm](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog3/) function mentioned within the *Mathematica* help system be of any service?
2. Does anybody have this integral already implemented? There are some series expansions quoted on the web, e.g. [Computation of the complete and incomplete Fermi-Dirac integral](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/210089.210090). However, the reference quotes that the series expansions converge rather slowly, and I would like to leave the implementation of the reference above as last resort, since this would take some time and maybe there is an easier way in *Mathematica*?

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: "Could the Nielsen generalized polylogarithm function mentioned within the *Mathematica* help system be of any service?" - so far as I can tell, no; there isn't a straightforward relationship between the incomplete FD integral and Nielsen's polylogarithm.

Comment: Anyway, if you're looking for quick-and-dirty numerical evaluation, you can use `NIntegrate[]` for the purpose. `Method -> "DoubleExponential"` is particularly convenient for the task.

Comment: "Does anybody have this integral already implemented?", yes, partially here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Fermi_002dDirac-Function.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I've noted in the comments, you can do a quick-and-dirty implementation using `NIntegrate[]` with the option setting `Method -> "DoubleExponential"`:

```
FermiDiracF[j_, x_] := FermiDiracF[j, x, 0];

FermiDiracF[j_, x_, b_] := 
 Module[{prec = Precision[{j, x, b}], bn, jn, mp, tmp, xn},
       mp = TrueQ[prec === MachinePrecision]; If[mp, prec = $MachinePrecision];
   {jn, xn, bn} = SetPrecision[{j, x, b}, prec + 5];
   tmp = Quiet[
          NIntegrate[t^jn/(E^(t - xn) + 1), {t, bn, Infinity},
                     Method -> "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> prec]/jn!,
          {NIntegrate::inum, NIntegrate::ncvi, NIntegrate::slwcon, NIntegrate::rnderr}];
   If[! FreeQ[tmp, NIntegrate], Return[$Failed]]; If[mp, N[tmp], tmp]] /;
 Positive[j] && (InexactNumberQ[j] || InexactNumberQ[x] || InexactNumberQ[b])
```

Some sample plots:

```
Plot[Table[FermiDiracF[j, 2, b], {j, {1/3, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2, 3}}] // Evaluate, {b, 0, 7}]
```

[image: plots of various incomplete Fermi-Dirac functions]

```
Plot3D[FermiDiracF[3/2, x, b], {x, -5, 5}, {b, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: surface plot of incomplete Fermi-Dirac function]

Comment: (One can of course do something similar for incomplete Bose-Einstein integrals...)

Comment: Is this better than just evaluating `N[PolyLog[...]]`?

Comment: `PolyLog[]` is useful for the *complete* integrals. The **incomplete** integrals do not admit a polylogarithmic representation, AFAIK.